# How to repair-unbrick-solve my Galaxy Tab 3 10.1" after rooting

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, unbricking, twrp, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

I was trying to root my device, but I think something went wrong. I may have bricked my Galaxy Tab 3 10.1.

When I noticed that the device was in loop, I tried to root with the `CF-Auto-Root` file a few times with Odin3-v3.07

The tablet doesn't start up. The only way to turn it on is to plug the USB cable in, then it starts and doesn't pass through Loading Screen where it says 'Samsung Galaxy Tab 3' something like that.

And when I connect into my PC, it starts up but keeps itself in a loop.

By loop i mean -> Turn on, Show Galaxy Tab 3, restart and show again...and again...and again...

Now i think i could get him to charge his battery..i hope at least, cause when he was in a loop i think he didn't charge as well as it should...

I try to go Recovery mode, to try to wipe those sys folders that we know can help in this loop scenario, but it just won't start recover mode, i think it did just now, but battery was low so to avoid further problems, he just says battery low or voltage low...something like that...too fast to read...And then he just turn off...

I do have TWRP to recover, i did a sys bkp before, is on my ExtSdCard, but i took it off from the slot for now...When i first saw on web that if not enough free space is available it can get to startup loop, but as i choose my ExtSdCard to save my Sys BKP i don't think that is the problem...Should i put it back in?

Sorry

Can someone give some hint, anything really?

Oh and i downloaded the ZTO version of firmware already to try out later...if i can't get it to at least work for boot...if...just if...
But i saw here that some have been able to unbrick so i'll die trying :D
I hope not literally..haha

Firmware that I downloaded is
`ZTO-P5200UBUAMF6-20130801180132.zip` ~1.1Gb

There are a few different types of bricked devices: hard brick, soft brick or coma brick. Which one applies to my situation?

---

I live in Brazil, so English is not my native language, sorry for any mistakes I might have made.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a custom recovery, just flash any [ROM for Galaxy Tab 3 10.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-3/development-10)

If your phone doesn't even boot, try flashing the stock image using ODIN.
This might help: [[HOW-TO] Unbrick Galaxy Tab 3 10.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2604681)

Comment: Ok, but in oder to do that, shouldn't  be on download mode?
apparently i can't set DownloadMode, so how can i do that...not even recovery mode....

Let's way for full charge of the battery and a'll try that...

Also, when i plug it on my PC, he just start up already by him self, i hear the  win sound when connects something on usb, and them imidiatly  the other sound, when is disconnected

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you bricked your phone. Fortunately Samsung devices are generally easy to recover from a Brick.

1. > "I do have TWRP to recover  i did a sys bkp before, is on my
   >   ExtSdCard, but i took it off from the slot for now"

   Good thinking. Insert that External SD card and perform a recovery from that.
2. A website that is essential for anyone rooting their phones is xda developers. There is a thread dedicated to what to do to recover from a bricked device [[HOW-TO] Unbrick Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 by Zachisimo](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2604681).

   This will take you step by step on how to recover to stock android. Once you recovered, you can always root again and install a custom rom (if you want to)